# How to benchmark a crate's WASM execution performance?

Tags: wasm, benchmark

How to benchmark the code's WASM execution performance?

I wrote a crate and want to use it in the runtime.

I want to know its WASM execution time in ms. How can I get that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FRAME is not a stand-alone WASM benchmarking framework. You can use criterion or similar for that.

The FRAME benchmarking is only concerned about the *Weight* of calls, not primarily miliseconds.
You could sure put the logic into a minimal pallet and call that. This can work, but is really not the intended use-case of the FRAME benchmarking. If you want to optimize the performance of low-level code it is better to go with other tools.

Comment: Yep, I agree with this. I want to write a "Rust" benchmark without any Substrate deps. Sure, I can use the criterion. But how can I the WASM performance? I don't want the native host benchmarking result. Then I can find some ways to transform that performance result to weight.

Comment: AFAIK criterion has first class WASM support. I have not used it so far, but it should be possible to compile it to WASM. There is a readme for [wasi](https://github.com/bheisler/criterion.rs/blob/2f5360737807cbe90d149db6199783236f0ef634/book/src/user_guide/wasi.md), maybe that helps. Note that Substrate uses wasmtime.